# Use a bootstrap3 modal, jquery and Rails 4 to create a parent object to my current model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sorry about the title, it's ugly and I imagine the code below is uglier.

I have a sales_opportunity model that belongs_to both a User and also a Company. (In this case, the User will be the salesman, and the Company will be the company he is trying to sell to). User and Company both belong_to Organization (the organization that the User works for).

When I create a new sales_opportunity I want the ability to add a Company using a modal (assuming that either no companies are currently in the database, or this is a new company that currently doesn't exist in the selection field). So far I've managed to get Jquery to add a "add new company" option to the selector dropdown, and to get an event listener to fire when this happens and bring up the bootstrap modal with the Company form within it (albeit the formatting is hideous, but that's not the point of this question). My issue is that Company.create is expecting an Organization_id to be passed through the URL in order to create this company. For example - if I just create a new Company from the Organizations/show page I use the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Add contact companies", new_company_path(organization_id: @organization.id), class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
```

Which works just fine.

For the modal code I've been following this example: http://ericlondon.com/2014/03/13/rails-4-submit-modal-form-via-ajax-and-render-js-response-as-table-row.html - but the problem is that this builds a User object from the Users.show page, and I am not on the right page to pass through Organization_id as far as I can tell.

My sales_opportunities controller:

```
  # GET /sales_opportunities/new
  def new
    @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.new(company_id: params[:company_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
    @pipeline_statuses = SalesOpportunity.pipeline_statuses
    @user = current_user
    @company = Company.new(organization_id: params[:organization_id])
  end
```

My companies form:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="well">
      <%= form_for(@company, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
        <% if @company.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
            <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
     <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :company_name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
        <div class ="col-md-8">
         <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
          <div class="checkbox input">
            <label>
            <%= f.check_box :existing_customer %> Existing Customer?
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :organization_id%>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn btn-success" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** I know that I need to add some parameters so that this knows when it's being called from a modal and when it's being called from a normal web request, I don't think this is the issue but please correct me if I'm wrong.

My javascript (currently I've just chucked this on the same form page as the sales_opportunity form, although I know I should convert it to coffeescript and put it in the asset pipeline).

```
//select the companies select dropdown and add in a "add new" item
  (function () {
    $('#sales_opportunity_company_id').append($('<option></option>', {
          text: 'Add new company',
        }))
    })();

//select the "add company" field and open a modal to insert a new company into the DB with Ajax
$('#sales_opportunity_company_id').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Add new company') {
    // Hide the submit button if "Add new company is selected"
    $('#submit').hide();
    var newvalue = false;
    //call a modal for adding a new company
    $('#competitor_modal').modal('show');
   /*if (newvalue) {
     //Some code to add the created company back into the select dropdown and have it as the selected option
  }
        else {
        $('#submit').show();
        }
});
</script>
```

My Modal callout:

```
<!-- modal for inputting a new company if none exists  -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="competitor_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="competitor_modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render "companies/form" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Has anyone else managed to achieve this? I'm thinking there must be some way for Jquery/AJAX to pass over the organization_id (or would it be JSON?) to the companies.create controller and then return the created object as an option in my selection list.

Sorry if this is a garbled mess - I only learned Jquery yesterday and as you can see I'm not much good at it.

Cheers.

Comment: Zoinks- do you want me to paste in code from y application where I pass data from Coffescript(javascript) to controller as well as passing data back to coffeescript ? Pierre

Comment: That would be great - I'd love to see some actual examples of how to make this happen. Thanks @user1854802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from app/assets/javascripts/companies/companies.js.coffee
Writtten in coffescript but I used cmd b to put into javascript

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  if ($('#x_company_drill_interests').length === 1) {
    return $('#x_company_drill_interests').change(function(event) {
      var company_id;
      company_id = $('.form.companies_drill_interests').attr('data-companyid');
      event.preventDefault();
      return calculateResult(company_id);
    });
 }
});
calculateResult = function(company_id) {
  var data;
  data = $('#x_company_drill_interests').serialize();
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/companies/" + company_id + "/projection.json",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    failure: function(data, success, xhr) {
      console.log(" -01- in calculateResult - Failure ");
      return console.log(data);
    },
    success: function(data, success, xhr) {
      var company_listings_block, compare_name, drill_name, name, result, result_row, table, target_share_price, total_target_share_price, _i, _len;
      compare_name = "";
      total_target_share_price = 0;
      company_listings_block = $('#x_company_listings_results .infogroup-body');
      ....
```

main screen which includes screen partial below

```
<% content_for :title, "Drill Investor" %>
<% content_for :tab_group, "companies" %> 
<% content_for :tab_id, 'company_drill_interests' %>
<div class="breadcrumbs"> 
  <%= link_to 'Company Details', company_details_path %> &raquo;  
  <%= @company.name %>
</div>
<section>
  <article class="single">
    <div class="form">
      <%= render 'company_info' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form companies_drill_interests" data-companyid="<%= @company.id %>">
```

company_id for navigation is set in the last line

```
calculateResult = function(company_id) {
  var data;
  data = $('#x_company_drill_interests').serialize();
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/companies/" + company_id + "/projection.json",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    failure: function(data, success, xhr) {
      console.log(" -01- in calculateResult - Failure ");
      return console.log(data);
   },
    success: function(data, success, xhr) {
      var company_listings_block, compare_name, drill_name, name, result, result_row, table, target_share_price, total_target_share_price, _i, _len;
      compare_name = "";
      total_target_share_price = 0;
      company_listings_block = $('#x_company_listings_results .infogroup-body');
      table = $('<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"></table>');
      ....
```

notes:
1- event.preventDefault(); is so that screen remain at same place on return
2- if ($('#x_company_drill_interests').length === 1) - determines screen has loaded and the tag, x_company_drill_interests, on the screeen partial _companies_drill_interests.html.erb (displayed below) is used to send data to the controller (pasted in below the screen partial.
3- also get company_id which i used in navigation.
4- In calculate_results I rspond to data the controller sends back (it get abit convoluted)

screen partial ( where I am getting data for above)
app/views/_companies_drill_interests.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @company,
       :html => { class: 'infogroup', 
       id: "x_company_drill_interests"  } do |f| %>
   <div class="infogroup-header">Drill Interests</div>
   <div class="infogroup-body"">
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="info"> 
       <th class="very_large_column lalign">Drill Name</th>   
       <th class="small_column ralign">Equity Percentage</th>
       <th class="very_small_column"><span></span></th>
       <th class="very_large_column">Saved Assumptions</span></th>
       <% if @drill_interests.present? %>
          ....
```

1- the @matched_avaluation_assumption stuff a little bit long winded

The controller app/controllers/companies.rb

```
  def projection
    @result_list = Array.new
    @company_listings.each do |cl|
      if @drill_interests.present?
        @drill_interests.each do |di|
          result = Hash.new
          # default price in case no user evaluation result found
          target_share_price = "Not saved"
          # now get, if present, the selected ser_evaluation_result 
          drill_interest = "foobar-" +di.id.to_s
          evaluation_assumption_id = params[drill_interest]
          row = UserEvaluationResult.matched_eval_result(evaluation_assumption_id, 
                                                          cl.id)
          target_share_price = row.target_share_price if row        
          result["cl_display_name"] = cl.display_name
          result["di"] = di.drill.name
          result["target_share_price"] = target_share_price
          @result_list << result
        end    
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @result_list }  
    end
  end
```

the revelant lines of interest are

```
  drill_interest = "foobar-" +di.id.to_s
  evaluation_assumption_id = params[drill_interest] 
  ....
```

---

HI Zoinksa.  My code coould be a lot better as well as DRYier.

Company_id.  In the main view companies_drill_interests.html.erb (same name as controller (see above - I pasted in some code) the line

```
<div class="form companies_drill_interests" data-companyid="<%= @company.id %>">
```

is what sets the company_id which is used for the routes. eg http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/companies/63/companies_drill_interests.

(1) I had a bit of trouble pasting in code - if you want I could give you temp. access to GitHub so you can look at code

(2) If you want to see code in action got to "http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/".  Login in as "pmlc" p/w "gmfive" select companies option (top RHS).  The select company = ADO.  Then select "Companies Drill Interests" tab/page and then change "Saved Assumption".  When you first go to this page the bottom third isdisplayed using ROR.  The second and subsequent time the bottom third is refreshed using Javascript.

Pierre - pmlc@iinet.net.au

Comment: Thanks Pierre. That's pretty in-depth code for me to wrap my mind around. I'll have a good look through it and ask any questions if I can't work things out. I appreciate your help.

Comment: should I write a separate partial to be used as the "form_for" or "simple_form_for" elements of my companies form? It strikes me that this wouldn't be very DRY, but it would allow me to have different formatting on that partial than I have for the existing partial (which is just rendered under companies/new or companies/edit anyway).

Comment: Sorry - accidentally hit enter. Also in the code: var company_id;
      company_id = $('.form.companies_drill_interests').attr('data-companyid'); - how is this accessing the company_id data from the companies_drill_interests form? In my app I'm on a page that has the User and the Sales_Opportunity id accessible; so presumably I need to get organization_id via current_user.organization.id (in Ruby). Is Javascript also able to pick up ruby results or should I be running this logic in the relevant controller?

Comment: Zoinks - I added some more stuff to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thanks - now I see how you're getting Javascript to pick up the company_id. Cheers for the help.